# how to draw smooth/anti-aliased circle in opengl?

Tags: smoothing, antialiasing

how do I draw smooth/anti-aliased circle in opengl? I am using glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP); to draw my circle but it is not smooth. 
I have enabled:

```
glEnable( GL_LINE_SMOOTH );
glHint( GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );
glEnable(GL_BLEND); 
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is years late, but the way I did it was using this tutorial.](https://www.desultoryquest.com/blog/drawing-anti-aliased-circular-points-using-opengl-slash-webgl/)

However, this only works for `GL_POINTS`.

For this to work, you also need to enable the `OES_standard_derivatives` extension.

Vertex:

```
attribute mediump vec4 Position;
attribute lowp float Size;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = Position;
    gl_PointSize = Size;
}
```

Fragment:

```
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable

void main(void) {
    lowp vec2 cxy = 2.0 * gl_PointCoord - 1.0;
    lowp float radius = dot(cxy, cxy);
    lowp float delta = fwidth(radius);
    lowp float alpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(1.0 - delta, 1.0 + delta, radius);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);
}
```